# Como faço para fazer mysql_num_rows de varios resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, o que pretendo é o seguinte:

Tenho 1 tabela designada por itens, nessa tabela tenho 4 colunas:

- nomeitem
- iditem (Id Único)
- numerobot

O que pretendo fazer é: Quero fazer um mysql_num_rows de todos os resultados, mas para cada nome do item diferente.

Ou seja suponhemos que eu tenho 10 resultados com o nome "Shadow Case", 15 resultados com o nome "Gamma Case".

O que pretendo é fazer isso, de forma a que saiba qual é a quantidade de cada item que eu tenho.

Para terminar pretendo pegar esses valores, e fazer um update a uma outra tabela que é designada por infoitens. Essa tabela apenas tem 2 colunas que são nomeitem e quantidade, onde na quantidade pretendo colocar o respetivo resultado anterior, para cada item.

Espero que me tenham entendido.

Comment: Só não entendi qual motivo de alimentar uma outra tabela sendo que você pode executar um script para obter estes dados a qualquer momento.
Estes dados não serão consolidados na tabela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode ser feito direto em uma consulta no MySQL:

```
SELECT nomeitem, count(nomeitem) as quantidade FROM tabela GROUP BY nomeitem;
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Com isso você tem a quantidade de cada item.

Pode pegar o resultado em um MySQLi_Result, ou dentro pode atualizar diretamente a outra tabela:

```
INSERT INTO outra_tabela (nomeitem, quantidade) 
SELECT nomeitem, count(nomeitem) as quantidade FROM tabela GROUP BY nomeitem;
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Porque esse "quantidade", está no selecT?

Comment: sobre "count(nomeitem) as quantidade", veja aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 3):

O `mysql_num_rows` não vai resolver facilmente.

Você pode fazer uma query normal que retorne o total de cada item:

```
SELECT nomeitem, COUNT(iditem) as total FROM tabela GROUP BY nomeitem;
```

Essa query ira retornar algo assim:

```
nomeitem       |total
----------------------
Shadow Case    |10 
Gamma Case     |15
```

Outra coisa, as funçôes `mysql_*` estão depreciadas, de preferencia as `mysqli_*` ou a classe `PDO`.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php